# Usb устройство - взаимодействие через rs232

Tags: usb, rs232, драйвер

Есть девайс ( чековый принтер ), который можно подключить к компьютеру через USB-RS232 переходник ( переходник втыкается в USB порт компьютера ) и работать с устройством через COM-порт который устанавливается вместе с драйвером переходника.

Но в случае если нет переходника, есть ли софтверное решение ? Т.е. устройство втыкаем напрямую в USB, ставим некий софтверный "переходник" в виде драйвера.
Есть ли такие решения ?

Comment: Не понял, у вас USB-устройство, вы подключаете его к компу через два переходника: USB-RS232 - RSR232-USB и сейчас вы хотите убрать эти переходники и вставлять напрямую USB-USB? Или устройство все-таки RS232? Тогда как вы собираетесь подключать его к USB? Если сами переходник можете сделать, то может и драйвер сами написать в состоянии?

Answer (score 2):

насколько я понял, устройство обладает последовательным интерфейсом *rs-232* (*serial-port*), и поддерживает работу лишь по этому интерфейсу.

тогда увы: интерфейс *usb* и интерфейс *rs-232* — абсолютно разные. как на электрическом, так и на логическом уровне.

вероятно, можно разработать микросхему контроллера, который сможет обрабатывать подключения устройств с обоими типами интерфейсов (возможно, такие даже и существуют). но, думаю, проще купить готовый копеечный «переходник» с микросхемой, уже «наученной» осуществлять все необходимые преобразования.